# How can i disable end date on reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i have a campaign date picker on my webpage. User should see all the dates for beginning of the campaign but when user pick a date for beginning it shouldn't pick end-date before today date. For example if my campaign beginning date is 06.01.2022 end-date value must be bigger than today date value some date like 10.02.2022 or bigger. Here is my code..

```
 <FormItem label={AddCampaignFormText.campaignStartAndEndDate} colSpan={{ span: 12 }}>
        <DatePicker.RangePicker
          name="campaignStartAndEndDate"
          validation={[{ required: true }]}
           disabledDate={disabledDate}
        />
      </FormItem>
```

Comment: Are you using `DatePicker` from `react-datepicker` ?

Comment: You need to handle onclick and then check for date selected, if the selected date is prior to the start date then you can make that date as a start date. Also you can disable the previous dates which you dont want user to select.

Comment: yes i'm using react-datepicker. Also i edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RangePicker from Antd. here it will do this automatically by default without having to set a `disabledDate` prop value.

Any date you select first will automatically  disable all the dates before that. Same if you select End Date first, it will disable all dates after that by default